# How to get the url of the directed page after login programatically

Tags: android

After login with username and password how to get the new URL that it would be directed. Plz help I dont know how to do that.

```
         protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
            try {
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost request = new HttpPost(UrlLink);
                List<NameValuePair> login = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                login.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login", "xxxxxxx"));
                login.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "yyyyyyyy"));
                login.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Login", "Login"));
                request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(login));
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                StatusLine line = response.getStatusLine();
                Log.v("line",response.getStatusLine().toString());
                int statuscode = line.getStatusCode();
                if (statuscode != 200) {
                    return null;
                }
            }

            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.v("Error", e.toString());
            }

            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement [RedirectHandler](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/RedirectHandler.html) or try `response.getHeaders("Location");`

If you are targeting *Gingerbread* or later, you can use `URLConnection`

Example:

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
  try {
    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
    // Will handle up to 5 redirects automatically
    String newURL = urlConnection.getURL();

  } finally {
    urlConnection.disconnect();
  }
}
```